# Explicitly route in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Am I able to route from within a function.  For instance, if the user presses the logout link I call a logout function in my accountController, I would also like this to cause the home view to be shown, since, if the user is on a profile page, it would need to go back to the default page.

```
 App.accountController = Em.ArrayController,create({
     logout: ->
         #do stuff to logout the person
         ...

         App.Router ( NEED TO TRANSITION TO HOME )
 })
```

So, I would like to explicitly call my router from here, to have the user go back to the home view.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this from more than place I would suggest creating a function on a mutual parent route (I'm using root because everything inherits from it) and calling `send` on the router

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
   root: Ember.Route.extend({
     goToHome: Ember.Route.transitionTo("root.home")
     //// Rest of route
     home: Ember.Route.extend({
     ////
```

And in your controller use:

```
App.router.send("goToHome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. You can get the router instance over App.get('router').

```
App.get('router').transitionTo('homeView')
```

Comment: It's good practice to not call transition to from outside the router. Actions should be sent to the router, which can call transitionTo in response to the action. The appropriate action may vary based on the current state of the router.

Comment: True that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: So is your approach to return a deferred object from the controllers method and then handle the transition in the .success() in the router?

Comment: Not sure what context you're asking about. Promises can be useful when you delegate to a controller or other object and want to transition on success. However, in that situation it is often better to fire a new event, since a state transition may have occurred since you gave up control to the async operation.

Answer (score 0):

Then just transition your router to that state. Something like:
App.get('router').transitionTo('root');